# Architecture Help for 2-tier list box

Tags: asp.net, architecture

*I'm sharing the images below need help in architecture design of list box with a list box.*

[image: Multi selection]

*As per image there is a building drop down but i will change that into list box when selecting multiple buildings need multiple selection of service streams, each building should have unique service streams. As i cannot post multiple times to create a building with streams.*

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is have a list box for buildings and in the service streams list, display all the entries for the buildings that are selected with the tag/label of the building(in brackets) they belong to. So this way, the user can see the list of service streams cumulatively for all the buildings that he has selected and then also select service stream based on the buildings that he has selected.

For example, the building list box contains: [b1, b2, b7]

Service stream list would contain:

s1  (b1)

s2  (b1)

s3  (b1)

s23 (b2)

s24 (b2)

s65 (b7)

Comment: Yes but if someone takes (b2)s2 then both are sharing same as per union

Comment: Or you can try rendering a set of service streams including the duplicates
(or) also have multiple buildings listed inside the brackets. Like s1(b1, b2, b7) if service stream s1 belongs to the buildings b1, b2, b3.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem. TIA